# how to enforce every request through a controller despite user opening a page

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

in MCV 2, if a user goes to a page (types the link) directly, the controller page will not be used. so how can the loging and security be performed?

how to force every direct page access to go through a controller page first?

I do need users to to access the web pages directly but want them to be routed through a controller.

Filters and putting JSPs in WEB-INF  will not allow to do that. and filters will not allow Google search engine too?

I do want calculations/logging to be made for every page that is to be accessed and at the same time want users to go to a page directly , and need no fuss for search engines.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but placing all JSPs in /WEB-INF filder will hide them from the user so no-one can access them directly

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I do need users to to access the web pages directly but want them to be routed through a controller.

Comment: It's not a problem (?) - name your controllers like pages and users won't notice. You don't need a controller for each and every page. Just have a wildcard mapping.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz  
makes sense. can you show a ready code that you made? if you have any, or any other thing/article  and you may make your comments as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add filter which will catch every request.

here is Apache Shiro example:

Notice that url-pattern matches everything

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: can you elaborate its use? and working? I do need users to to access the web pages directly but want them to be routed through a controller.

Comment: Filter is to do some stuff before request goes to servlet. At least its one of the use cases. You can drop request or reroute it depending on what you want to do, or pass it to another filter. I don't really know what you want to do exactly.

Comment: @masood every request goes through servlet if pages are placed inside WEB-INF folder. Question is: Do you want to make some work before serving static content? Because I'm guessing thats what you do, you serve some static webpage

Comment: thanks for replying, I do want calculations/loging to be made for every page that is to be accessed and at the same time want users to go to a page directly , and need no fuss for search engines.      and   "every request goes through -?-?-"servlet"-?-?- if pages are placed inside WEB-INF folder."

Comment: well user always can go to the page directly if you do not redirect him then he will see the page. Filter can do the job with logging and calculations assuming that all you need to do calculations can be found in http request. For example you will one filter which does the calculations/logging and bunch of jsp's with url mappings and jsp's are inside web-inf folder.

Comment: makes sense. can you show a ready code that you made? if you have any, or any other thing/article

Comment: here you have some tutorial about filters. My code in on private repository so I cannot post it here. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/

Answer (score 1):

Place your all jsp files in WEB-INF folder... Then user cann't access that jsp path directly... Its  secured flow... In every jsp path you should add prefix of WEB-INF. Your path will be WEB-INF/home.jsp

Comment: how to let users get the page directly then? and how to involve the controller at the same time?